# How to iterate through all checkboxes on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do  I can  iterate through all checkboxes on the page with JQuery?

I.e. I have those `checkboxes` above...

```
<div>
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="option_1" id="checkbox_1" value="1" />35 MM                  
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="option_2" id="checkbox_2" value="2" />  DIGITAL                    
<input type="checkbox" name="option_3" id="checkbox_3" value="3" /> 3D DIGITAL
</div>
```

Have I use

```
 $('input[id^="checkbox_"]').each(function() {

 });
```

Is it correct? Thank you!

Comment: Assuming you **only** want inputs that have an ID beginning with "checkbox_" then yes, that code is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this to iterate through the checkboxes:

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
   });
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('name'); // grab name of original
  var value = $(this).attr('value'); // grab value of original
  var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked"); //check if checked
});
```

Comment: Please don't use the .attr('checked'), read this article: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ to know why.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery supports a selector `:checkbox` that is just for selecting checkboxes on the page so if you want all checkboxes on the page that's the simplest way to do it:

```
$(":checkbox").each(function(index, element) {
    // put your code here
});
```

In the [jQuery doc for `:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/), they recommend that this selector might perform slightly faster:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(index, element) {
    // put your code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It seem alright but you can add further type check to ensure not other control type with mataching id comes in selector.

```
$('input[type=checkbox][id^="checkbox_"]').each(function() {

 });
```